# How can I return the index of a vector?

Tags: java, vector

I read through the java doc fro Vector and cant see how I can return the index number of a vector after I have just added an element to it .
Im trying to do something along these lines :

```
vec.addElement(new Person(Number,firstName,familyName));

int lastPersonIndex = vec.RETURN THE LAST INDEX();
```

I tried using lastElement but that returns an object and I want it to be stored in an int.I couldnt work out how I cast this  (cant cast an object to an int can you?)

you can see im at beginner level , so any help appreciated

N.B just to add i know there are newer ways that are recommended than using vectors but this is part of a homework and we were taught vectors so I want to use them within a piece of work im doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the [size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#size%28%29) of the Vector,

```
int lastPersonIndex = vec.size() - 1; // minus 1 because of 0 based counting.
```

Comment: omg yes - its so simple now you say it. thanks. I think i was over thinking that one.I will accept your answer as correct in 10 mins as wont allow it right away. In fact it will be vec.size()-1 to return the index. But yes that works.

Answer (score 1):

You should return the vector size - 1:

```
int lastPersonIndex = vec.size() - 1;
```